# How to change the language shown on login screen and logout screen?

Tags: windows-10

I bought my PC in Japan, I have changed language on Settings to English, but it is still Japanese on login screen and logout screen. How to change that to English also?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide the screenshots that indicate you have uninstalled the unused Japanese language pack?

Comment: @Ramhound After I remove Japanese language pack, it became English now! Butthanks. Let me reinstall Japanese language again, as I need to input Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

In Run dialog (Winkey+R) type `control international` and go to the *Administrative* tab and click *Copy Settings*. This copies the user's language settings to the logon screen.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, even your Operating System language is configured as English, in the Windows login page English page won’t be as default and you have to change the language.

Please try to: Settings> Language> Administrative language settings> copy settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxjNX.png)